# How to force Karma to watch it's own configuration file (karma.conf.js)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

I am starting with angular.js development...

I did notice karma does not watch for it's own configuration file (karma.conf.js), neither if  I add it to dependencies 'files' array...

I don't know if it's by design, but I find it quite annoying, since I'm just starting with karma/jasmine, and I frequently tune configuration parameteres...

Is there some way to force karma watch for it's own configuration file?

**UPDATE:**
Enabling logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG I see:

```
WARN [watcher]: All files matched by "/app-base-path/karma.conf.js" were excluded.
```

So, it's excluded by design...

Can anybody explain the rationale behind this decision?

Comment: configuration files must be available in the full bootstrap process, as they mostly set parameters that will not change throughout the application lifecycle, so  i suppose the karma runner enforces relaunch if any of them changes.

Comment: Thant's what I'd expect, but it isn't relaunched... I use a "grunt serve" command line, with a "yeoman" standard Gruntfile.js ...

Comment: that's because the watch mechanism only reloads certain files (and *not* performing the entire bootstrap for every change).

Comment: So, what should I do to force a test on karma.conf.js change?

Comment: not very much, it's fundamentally undesired. stick to the design and just relaunch when you change the configuration.

Comment: You did convince me, I'll stick to design.... :-)

Comment: If it still bugs you, perhaps you should rephrase your question to *How to force watch on karma configuration files?*, or post another one, rather than asking *if* it's possible. I believe once it's asked that way, sure enough *someone* will take the challenge :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Karma does not do that right now, but you are right - it should!**

It bugs me everyday but apparently didn't bug me enough to actually do it. It's not super trivial to do and some of the config properties will require complete re-bootstrap.

Anyway, [here](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/595) is the ticket for it. Feel free to send a pull request. I'm also happy to discuss possible ways how to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Vojta... And thanks for your work... :-) I'm afraid suppose I'm not ready for a pull request, not so confident with JS, yet... :-) By the way, is it true Karma has been 'obsoleted' by Protractor, for e2e?

Comment: Yep it is true. I mean, we deprecated the Angular Scenario runner (which Karma could run) in favor of Protractor which is implemented on the top of WebDriver. I think WebDriver is the future for e2e testing. It does not mean that we are deprecating Karma. Not at all. Karma's focus is on unit testing.